# column not found (Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swbRj.png)

It's saying column does not exists after migrating using sequelize-cli. all the columns are defined in migration file but still this error pops out. Also when creating model instance it says "errorMissingColumn".

[why sequelize is returning a unknown field from my table that doesn't exists called UserId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHBJz.png)

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding a foreignKey manually instead of default one created by sequelize.